# PHP creates files as root user instead of nginx

Tags: linux, php, debian, users, user-permissions

I've set up a new server on Debian Stretch.

The web server user is nginx:

```
ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1

nginx
```

I have already set the web server path to 775 and nginx recursively.

```
chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/html/
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html
```

When I create a file, the user is root with the following permissions:

```
<?php file_put_contents ('/var/www/html/settings/test.json', 'Test file'); ?>
```

```
php test.php

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9 Apr 29 09:19 /var/www/html/settings/test.json
```

What else can I try?

Comment: php scripts are note executed by nginx, but by the php-fpm process. Most probabyly it's running as root (which it shouldn't ).

Comment: How do I check which user php is running as? It is started from Supervisor.

Comment: What do the `user` and `group` lines say in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`?

Comment: They are both nginx

Comment: I think I have figured it out partly. I did: `chgrp -R nginx /var/www/html`. Now I get `-rw-r--r-- 1 root nginx 9 Apr 29 11:57 /var/www/html/settings/test.json`

Comment: Actually, spoke too soon. Updating the file with php changes it back to root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run PHP from the command line when you are logged in as root, then the PHP binary will execute as root. This means the files it creates are owned by root.

To properly test your setup, you need to execute the PHP script by calling it via http / nginx. For example:

```
curl http://example.com/test.php
```

Comment: You're right, creating a file via http creates the file as nginx.

It's causing me permission problems because the files are written to by both http and a backend process. How can I make the files work for both?

Comment: You should run the backend process as the user as nginx is running as.

Comment: The backend process is run by Supervisor. I've just tried setting the user to ngnix and restarting but the process is still running as root.

Comment: Actually, If I set `user=nginx` in supervisord.conf, the process will not start.

Comment: Then you need to find out why the process does not start as another user and fix that issue.